# Differentiating ParametricNDSolve solutions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Is there any way to differentiate a solution obtained by [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)? For instance, I have the position $\phi_\gamma(t)$ as a function of time, parametrized by the constant $\gamma$. Now I want to differentiate with respect to time but keep the result a [`ParametricFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricFunction.html). If my solution is called `xp`, simply writing `D[xp,t]` does not work, and it does not seem possible to seek for a solution of $\frac{d}{dt} \phi_\gamma(t)$ in the command of `NDSolve` or `ParametricNDSolve`, although one can differentiate an `InterpolationFunction` obtained by `NDSolve`. So, is there a way to differentiate a `ParametricFunction` with respect to the variable (or the parameter)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
β = ω0/4; ω = 2 π; ω0 = 3/2 ω;
tend = 500;
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + 
      2 β x'[t] + ω0^2 Sin[
        x[t]] == γ ω0^2 Cos[ω t], x[0] == 0, 
    x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, tend}, γ, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[D[s[γ][t], t]], {t, 50, 100}], {γ, 0.1, 
  1}]
```

If you select `ParametricNDSolve` and press F1 this will take you to the documentation, there you will find many more examples.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that `D[s[\[Gamma]][t], t]` just works once you have $\gamma$ assigned a value. I was making the mistake of trying `D[s, t]` without specifying the variables.